# degree decimal to utm conversion, python

Tags: python, coordinates, gis, utm

I got surprised when I tried to convert degree decimal coordinates into utm by using available library in anaconda`utm`.

my coordinates looks like:

```
lon = array([83.71666667, 83.7       , 83.6       , 83.65      , 83.6       ,
       83.88333333, 83.56666667, 83.88333333, 83.96666667, 83.75      ,
       83.7       , 83.1       , 83.21666667, 83.73333333, 83.65      ,
       83.4       , 83.56666667, 84.        , 83.78333333, 83.68333333,
       83.6       , 83.48333333, 83.3       , 83.38333333, 83.61666667,
       83.98333333, 83.43333333, 83.53333333, 84.05      , 84.21666667,
       83.15      , 83.06666667, 83.26666667, 83.25      , 83.8       ,
       84.9       , 84.36666667, 84.        , 83.88333333, 84.61666667,
       84.35      , 84.41666667, 84.61666667, 83.81666667, 84.11666667,
       83.81666667, 83.8       , 84.1       , 84.23333333, 84.28333333,
       83.96666667, 84.01666667, 83.8       , 84.61666667, 84.1       ,
       83.76666667, 84.13333333, 83.75      , 83.78333333, 83.91666667,
       85.        , 84.28333333, 84.41666667, 84.53333333, 85.13333333,
       85.05      , 85.01666667, 84.81666667, 84.98333333, 84.43333333,
       85.38333333, 84.81666667, 85.01666667, 84.93333333, 85.25      ,
       85.18333333, 85.31666667, 85.3       , 85.11666667, 85.41666667,
       85.25      , 85.54722   ])
```

and lat values are:

```
lat = array([28.78333333, 28.75      , 28.26666667, 28.48333333, 28.63333333,
       28.81666667, 28.35      , 29.05      , 29.18333333, 28.18333333,
       28.21666667, 28.4       , 28.6       , 28.4       , 28.03333333,
       28.38333333, 28.15      , 29.1       , 28.96666667, 28.9       ,
       28.46666667, 28.38333333, 28.05      , 28.56666667, 28.13333333,
       29.18333333, 27.95      , 27.86666667, 27.68333333, 27.68333333,
       27.93333333, 27.55      , 28.01666667, 28.06666667, 27.86666667,
       28.36666667, 28.28333333, 28.21666667, 28.1       , 28.06666667,
       28.13333333, 27.93333333, 28.        , 27.88333333, 28.11666667,
       28.26666667, 28.3       , 28.03333333, 28.55      , 27.96666667,
       28.26666667, 28.06666667, 28.38333333, 28.2       , 28.36666667,
       27.98333333, 27.86666667, 28.26666667, 28.26666667, 28.08333333,
       28.48333333, 28.76666667, 27.61666667, 27.58333333, 27.55      ,
       27.41666667, 27.41666667, 27.55      , 27.43333333, 27.06666667,
       28.28333333, 28.05      , 27.91666667, 27.86666667, 27.8       ,
       27.71666667, 28.01666667, 28.1       , 28.01666667, 27.75      ,
       27.75      , 28.20946   ])
```

when I made scatter plot it looks like normal:

[image]

After converting coordinates in to utm distribution of the points change completely and looks strange like in this figure:

[image]

the code that i used to conver is:

```
import utm
X = []
Y = []
for i in np.arange(len(lat)):
    LAT,LON,Z,S = utm.from_latlon(lat[i],lon[i])
    X = np.append(X,LON)
    Y = np.append (Y,LAT)
```

as suggested in comments: I switch lon lat positn i.e,
`plt.scatter (Y,X)` it gives:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong, or is this result correct?

Comment: [`from_latlon`](https://pypi.org/project/utm/) returns the easting first and the northing second, you have them the other way round.

Comment: @acraig5075 by changing the position, it does not solve the problem. I have added figure after changing position too..

Comment: I suspect that this happens because your longitudes straddle two UTM zones, zone 43 (78°-84°) and zone 44 (84°-90°).

Comment: @TurePålsson, yes these data are from two utm zones. Is there anyways to force to convert by using one zone lets say by usign only zone 44??

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you there, as I am not familiar with the library you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer might be helpful for others so I have posted my solution. I found `pyproj` works better then `utm`. In pyproj we can specify utm zone.

`import pyproj`

`from pyproj import Proj`

```
myProj = Proj("+proj=utm +zone=45U, +north +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
lon_,lat_ = myProj(lon, lat) 
plt.scatter(lon_,lat_)
```

and the figure looks good!

[image]